# Gap in $p$-adic proof of Nagell-Lutz theorem

Tags: proof-explanation, elliptic-curves, p-adic-number-theory, projective-space

A common approach to proving the Nagell-Lutz theorem is to use a "$p$-adic filtration" $E(\mathbb{Q}_p) \supset E^0 \supset E^1 \supset \dotsb$, which has several properties including that every point in $E^n$ with homogeneous coordinates $(x:y:z)$ must satisfy $y \neq 0$ and $x/y \in p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Next, apply the key lemma ([Lemma 5.9 in Milne](http://www.jmilne.org/math/Books/ectext5.pdf), and [Lemma 9.3.2 in these lecture notes](https://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/anni/ma426-ellipticcurves/chapter9.pdf)) that for all $P_1,P_2,P_3 \in E(\mathbb{Q}_p)$, with $P_i = (x_i:y_i:z_i)$,
$$
P_1 + P_2 + P_3 = O \implies \frac{x_1}{y_1} + \frac{x_2}{y_2} + \frac{x_3}{y_3} \in p^{5n}\mathbb{Z}_p
$$

There seems to be a gap in both proof of this lemma that I linked to: they both say that assuming that $P_1 \neq P_2$, the line joining those two points is $z = \alpha x + \beta$, where we have set $y = 1$. Then they compute $v_p(\alpha)$ and $v_p(\beta)$. But shouldn't the line in general be $\alpha x + \beta y + \gamma z = 0$, where $\gamma$ could be zero, failing to give the form $z = \alpha x + \beta$?

Or is there some reason that $\gamma \neq 0$?

Comment: No! in the last line of the proof of Milne's book (lemma 5.9) he said: "The proof when $P_1=P_2$ is similar."